# How to programmatically read-write scripts for offline usage in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to have predefined scripts, accessible from chrome content_script, that could be updated automatically from given URL.

**Exactly what i do:**

I have content_script.js. Inside it, i`d like to create iframe for current page from predefined html+css+js.Sometimes html or css or js can be changed. I want to avoid updating extension, instead, each time user have internet, he could load fresh html+css+js for further offline usage.

So, how to read and write some internal files within extension from content script (or delegate this task to background script)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML5 Filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to have a read/write place for files, or just store it as strings in `chrome.storage` (with `"unlimitedStorage"` permission as needed) for later reuse.

This code can then be executed in a content script using `executeScript`, or, if you enable `'unsafe-eval'` for the extension CSP, in the main script (which is dangerous, and should be avoided in most cases).

Note that this Filesystem API has a warning that's it's only supported in Chrome, but that shouldn't be a problem (Firefox / WebExtensions platform explicitly reject self-update mechanisms).

Comment: Could we use this api to write to extension folder?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Sorry for lack of response - no, an extension cannot self-modify (and if it did, it would result in immediate disabling as an anti-tampering measure). HTML5 Filesystem is virtual and is not mapped to any folder on a real filesystem.

Comment: thanks for the info, so for this question alone, the answer should be no since there is no way for extensions to modify itself (except updates).

Comment: But you can always eval code that you can store somewhere. `eval("...")` for main code, `executeScript({code: "..."})` for content scripts.

Comment: I probably don't figure out your method, if you mean `eval`, I think maybe it is a little ... ugly.

Comment: It's ugly, it's evil, and it's the only way. Filesystem is not needed though, you can just as well store code in `chrome.storage`.

Comment: so for this question, the author would need to download some "fresh code" and use `eval` to change the runtime behavior, but not the extension files itself (like deleting some code), right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. Note that while Chrome Web Store does not expressly forbid it *to the best of my knowledge*, Mozilla does.

Comment: so what about updating this answer if convenient? We may not hit on `eval` at the first glance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107002/discussion-between-xan-and-haibara-ai).

Answer (score 1):

You can do read extension file contents, but you can't write to **extension folder** since it is sandboxed.

To read an extension file, you can just send Ajax call using `chrome.runtime.getURL("filepath")` as url

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', chrome.runtime.getURL('your file path'), true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (chr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        var text = xhr.responseText;
        // Do what you want using text
    }
};
xhr.send();
```